# REDIS high memory usage

Tags: memory, redis

We have written 6.7M keys with value size of 600 bytes. Total memory usage expected is 4.2GB but we are noticing rss memory usage of 5.7GB.

Why does redis use extra 2GB of memory?

**memory info command output**

```
     info memory
# Memory
used_memory:5913620368
used_memory_human:5.51G
used_memory_rss:6065446912
used_memory_rss_human:5.65G
used_memory_peak:5913639024
used_memory_peak_human:5.51G
used_memory_peak_perc:100.00%
used_memory_overhead:338769120
used_memory_startup:1018080
used_memory_dataset:5574851248
used_memory_dataset_perc:94.29%
allocator_allocated:5913554768
allocator_active:6065409024
allocator_resident:6065409024
total_system_memory:34359738368
total_system_memory_human:32.00G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
used_memory_scripts:0
used_memory_scripts_human:0B
number_of_cached_scripts:0
maxmemory:0
maxmemory_human:0B
maxmemory_policy:noeviction
allocator_frag_ratio:1.03
allocator_frag_bytes:151854256
allocator_rss_ratio:1.00
allocator_rss_bytes:0
rss_overhead_ratio:1.00
rss_overhead_bytes:37888
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.03
mem_fragmentation_bytes:151892144
mem_not_counted_for_evict:3738
mem_replication_backlog:0
mem_clients_slaves:0
mem_clients_normal:17440
mem_aof_buffer:4096
mem_allocator:libc
active_defrag_running:0
lazyfree_pending_objects:0
```

**number of keys in redis**

```
info keyspace
# Keyspace
db6:keys=6765516,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check this https://redis.io/topics/faq :

64-bit systems will use considerably more memory than 32-bit systems to store the same keys, especially if the keys and values are small. This is because **pointers take 8 bytes in 64-bit systems**. But of course the advantage is that you can have a lot of memory in 64-bit systems, so in order to run large Redis servers a 64-bit system is more or less required. The alternative is shardi

Comment: Even with 8 byte per pointer, why does memory used goes up to 5.9GB when total key+value size ~4.2GB.

Comment: What’s your data type? Is it hash???

Comment: Yes. It is a hash with few fields out of which one is 600 bytes and other than ~10 bytes.

Comment: How many Key does each hash have?

Comment: 3 fields out of which 1 field is 600 bytes and others are less than 10 bytes